# adding php code inside html in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having event organizer and event venues need to add one line code in html file for displaying if it is venue to show as venue and it is organizer to show as organizer.as i have tried that by adding like below format but got an error as

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\live\wp-content\plugins\the-events-calendar\src\Tribe\Linked_Posts.php on line 943
```

This is the code:

```
echo '<input
            type="hidden"
            class="tribe-dropdown linked-post-dropdown"
            name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '"
            id="saved_' . esc_attr( $post_type ) . '"
            data-placeholder="' . $placeholder . '"
            data-search-placeholder="' . $search_placeholder . '" ' .
            ( $creation_enabled ?
            'data-freeform
            data-sticky-search
            data-create-choice-template="' . __( 'Click to create new "' . <?php printf( esc_html__( '%s:', 'the-events-calendar' ), $this->singular_name ); ?> . '": <b><%= term %></b>', 'the-events-calendar' ) . '"
            data-allow-html ' : '' ) .
            'data-options="' . esc_attr( json_encode( $data ) ) . '"' .
            ( empty( $current ) ? '' : ' value="' . esc_attr( $current ) . '"' ) .
        '>';
```

i have this line code to display that

```
<?php printf( esc_html__( '%s:', 'the-events-calendar' ), $this->singular_name ); ?>
```

Comment: @KirkBeard i have done this unfortunately it is not working

Comment: @KirkBeard it is getting the same error messahe

Answer (score 0):

**remove php code in printf( esc_html__( '%s:', 'the-events-calendar' ), $this->singular_name );**

```
<?php
echo '<input
            type="hidden"
            class="tribe-dropdown linked-post-dropdown"
            name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '"
            id="saved_' . esc_attr( $post_type ) . '"
            data-placeholder="' . $placeholder . '"
            data-search-placeholder="' . $search_placeholder . '" ' .
            ( $creation_enabled ?
            'data-freeform
            data-sticky-search
            data-create-choice-template="' . __( 'Click to create new "' .printf( esc_html__( '%s:', 'the-events-calendar' ), $this->singular_name ). '": <b><%= term %></b>', 'the-events-calendar' ) . '"
            data-allow-html ' : '' ) .
            'data-options="' . esc_attr( json_encode( $data ) ) . '"' .
            ( empty( $current ) ? '' : ' value="' . esc_attr( $current ) . '"' ) .
        '>';
?>
```

Comment: If i add like that it is printing all the  data present in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($post_type == 'tribe_venue'){

            echo '<input
            type="hidden"
            class="tribe-dropdown linked-post-dropdown"
            name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '"
            id="saved_' . esc_attr( $post_type ) . '"
            data-placeholder="' . $placeholder . '"
            data-search-placeholder="' . $search_placeholder . '" ' .
            ( $creation_enabled ?
            'data-freeform
            data-sticky-search
            data-create-choice-template="' . __( 'Click to create new venue: <b><%= term %></b>', 'the-events-calendar' ) . '"
            data-allow-html ' : '' ) .
            'data-options="' . esc_attr( json_encode( $data ) ) . '"' .
            ( empty( $current ) ? '' : ' value="' . esc_attr( $current ) . '"' ) .
        '>';

        }else{

            echo '<input
            type="hidden"
            class="tribe-dropdown linked-post-dropdown"
            name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '"
            id="saved_' . esc_attr( $post_type ) . '"
            data-placeholder="' . $placeholder . '"
            data-search-placeholder="' . $search_placeholder . '" ' .
            ( $creation_enabled ?
            'data-freeform
            data-sticky-search
            data-create-choice-template="' . __( 'Click to create new organizer: <b><%= term %></b>', 'the-events-calendar' ) . '"
            data-allow-html ' : '' ) .
            'data-options="' . esc_attr( json_encode( $data ) ) . '"' .
            ( empty( $current ) ? '' : ' value="' . esc_attr( $current ) . '"' ) .
        '>';

        }
```

This solution worked fine